# HTML heading elements in labels

Tags: html, html-heading

When I need place a title, I use `h-number` tags. But in case that I need a title in a `label`, for instance, should I use `h-number`, too?

**Example:**

```
<label ...>
    <h1>Username</h1>
    <input ... />
</label>
```

Comment: Why would you think that this is _not_ a good idea?

Comment: Depends on the context. What you have given is correct.

Comment: I don't know if I really can use it on small things. Should I?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, just remember that there should be an order to things. See my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do so. Just use styles

```css
label,
label span {font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<label for="username-input">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username-input">

<!-- Or, if you want the input inside of the label -->
<label>
  <span>Username</span>
  <input type="text" name="username">
</label>
```

Generally, you do not want to put block elements (such as heading tags) inside of inline elements (such as a label). However, you can always alter their display style.

Another thing to remember is that heading tags should be reserved for headings. Label tags should be reserved for labels. **In your case**, the `h1` tag inside of the label doesn't "make sense" since it is not the heading of the page. You would want to use something *less prominent*, such as a `span`, but make it look how you want.

Comment: In other words, if it’s _semantically_ a heading, use a heading element, if it’s _purely presentational_, use CSS.

Comment: If I put the `input` inside the `label`, I don't need the `[for]` attribute.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues correct

Answer (score 2):

A label should be used as a *caption* and does not require `<h1> <h2>` etc. Valid markup would look like

```
<label>
    Username
    <input />
</label>
```

Feel free to move the `<input />` outside of the `<label />` by using the `for=` attribute, or keep the `<input />` inside your label as you have it.

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input id="username" type="text" />
```

[See more here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)