# Element h3 not allowed as child of element label in this context

Tags: html

I have currently this code:

```
<ul class="char">
  <li>
    <label class="textOverImage" style="background-image:url(img/text.png)">
       <input type="checkbox">
       <h3>Joyce Byers</h3>
       <div>
           text
       </div>
    </label>
  </li>
```

w3.validator.org gives me these errors:

> Element h3 not allowed as child of element label in this context.

> Element div not allowed as child of element label in this context.

I really don't know another way to do this. Is there a way to get what I want without an error?

I'm trying to make this: https://codepen.io/zFunx/pen/QvzeBN

Comment: why do you need h3?  you can use span and style that span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code, you have

```
<label class="textOverImage" style="background-image:url(img/text.png)">
     <input type="checkbox">
     <h3>Joyce Byers</h3>
     <div>
         text
     </div>
</label>
```

Which means inside your `label`, you have an input, a `h3` and a `div`.
The only things you can have inside a `label` is text and/or an `input`.
You need to move the `div` and the `h3` out of the `label` or use something else than a `label` to group the `h3` and the `div`

Comment: I'm trying to create this https://codepen.io/zFunx/pen/QvzeBN

What should I use instead of label to group h3 and div?
That would be the best i suppose.

Comment: This codepen is not valid html, it is possible but you won't be able to use this example

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of these scenarios :

```
<label for="username-input">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username-input">

<!-- Or, if you want the input inside of the label -->
<label>
<span>Username</span>
<input type="text" name="username">
</label>
```

you can find more information in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838504/html-heading-elements-in-labels)